# How to get public directory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am a beginner here so pardon me for this question am using `return File::put($path , $data);` to create a file in public folder on Laravel. I used this piece of code from controller I need to know the value of `$path` how should it be.

Comment: are you using Laravel 3 or Laravel 4?

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Try [public_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-public-path). It is possible to adjust a path. For example:

```php
// Path to the 'public/css' directory.
echo public_path('css');
```

---

For a reference, there are more methods, including:

```php
// Path to the project's root directory.
echo base_path();

// Path to the 'app' directory.
echo app_path();

// Path to the 'resources' directory.
echo resource_path();

// Path to the 'storage' directory.
echo storage_path();

// ...
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#paths

Comment: Just to add that `public_path()` is actually pretty useless- it just assumes all your public files are in a directory called "public"- even if they aren't. For example, I always have to change the default "public" directory to "public_html" (in line with my server). Laravel doesn't recognise this. So don't rely on this to make any intelligent determination of what your public directory actually is. I'm just using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` unless anyone can suggest why I shouldn't?

Comment: @inigo it is not useless, you are just not using it as it was intended. If you want to change the directory of public, you need to tell Laravel about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758901/laravel-5-change-public-path?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 23):

You can use base_path() to get the base of your application - and then just add your public folder to that:

```
$path = base_path().'/public';
return File::put($path , $data)
```

Note: Be **very** careful about allowing people to upload files into your root of public_html. If they upload their own index.php file, they will take over your site.

Comment: is base_path defined in laravel .. i used it i got this error Call to undefined function base_path()

Comment: Yes - it is defined in helpers.php. I tested in on my L4 app - it works. Make sure you are running the latest L4 build - it might not have been in the earlier versions.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a little late, but if someone else comes across this looking, you can now use public_path(); in Laravel 4, it has been added to the helper.php file in the support folder [see here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L764).

Answer (score 9):

The best way to retrieve your public folder path from your Laravel config is the function:

```
$myPublicFolder = public_path();
$savePath = $mypublicPath."enter_path_to_save";
$path = $savePath."filename.ext";
return File::put($path , $data);
```

There is no need to have all the variables, but this is just for a demonstrative purpose.

Hope this helps,
GRnGC

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is asset(''); You can use asset('storage'), after creating your symbolic link.

Comment: `asset_path("")` did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `asset()` function;
for example,
you have image.png in the assets folder in the public dir
ie: `public/assets/image.png`
You can access it by:

```
$image = asset('assets/image.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
asset('public')
```

OR

```
url('public')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a public directory in laravel controller:

you can use

```php
$custom_url = "sdefrghj";
$filename="assets/".$custom_url.'-question-list.csv';
```

hope you get it :-)