# Laravel 5 change public_path()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to move the `public` folder to other place. However, I can't find the place to modify `public_path()` variable. Now, the 'public_path()' return the wrong path of folder.

Where can I set the variable for `public_path()`?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can override the public path using ioc container :

What worked for me flawlessly was adding to `public/index.php` the following three lines:

```
 $app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

[For more detailed explanation click here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5)

Comment: Tried with your solution, it works on display webpages. However, it doesn't work for artisan command. The artisan still refer `public_path` to the default public path.

Comment: @user1995781 you can apply the same code in the file "artisan" which is the "index.php" of the command.

Comment: Thanks for providing the reference link too.

Answer (score 50):

While accepted answer works for requests coming from HTTP, it will not work for `artisan`.

If you need `artisan` to know your custom public path, you need to extend Laravel main Application class. I know it sounds scary, but it's actually very simple.

All you need to do is following:
**Step 1:** In the file: `bootstrap/app.php` change the very first declaration of `$app` variable

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

to reflect your own custom Application class:

```
$app = new App\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

**Step 2:** Define your custom Application class somewhere. For example in `app/Application.php`

```
<?php namespace App;

class Application extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
{
}
```

Congrats! You have extended Laravel core Application class.

**Step 3:** Overwrite the `publicPath` method. Copy and paste Laravel original method to **your new class** and change it to your needs. In my particular case I did like this:

```
public function publicPath()
{
    return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public_html';
}
```

That's it! You can overwrite any method in Application class the same way.

Comment: Regarding `Step 3` ... where in /bootstrap/app.php should I be putting that override?

Comment: @dcolumbus This should not go to bootstrap/app.php file. It should be in you custom `Application` class, which is extending Laravel core (step 2) and therefor overriding Laravel core `publicPath` method.

Comment: I originally had the declaration in my index.php file, which worked for regular http requests. I came to an error when running PHPunit, it said "File (...) not defined in asset manifest". The reason was that it couldn't find the asset manifest because it wasn't looking in the right public folder. The solution you demonstrate here solved that. So it works for HTTP, artisan ánd PHPunit. It should really be the accepted answer!

Comment: Scary yea, but it works. But i don't understand why this part `'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.` I have this `return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public_html'` for shared host.

Comment: @FONGOHMARTIN `..` is a name for parent directory in Linux, while `.` is a current directory. Which means, I have public_html dir one level up from the basePath, not inside it.

Comment: Yea @ruuter you right. I fixed it. Your approach is perfectly correct. Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: I did this, but im not understanding how to adjust blade relative/ or root paths.  I thought that would fix it there too.  Note, my public path had to be in a subdir, since laravel is one piece of a larger site, e.g. `../html/public` blade e.g. `{{asset('css/styles.css')}}` is not finding correct path, but `{{asset('public/css/styles.css')}}` is.  how can i eliminate the `public/` portion?

Comment: @blamb it should work. If `public/css` works, then your public path must be set one level too high. It points to `html` not `html/public`

Answer (score 28):

I suggest you add it in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
    });
}
```

This affects `artisan` as well.

Comment: why this affect the artisan?

Comment: This doesn't work in some config cases! Be careful! But the index.php one worked.

Answer (score 10):

In laravel 5.6 this work for me ... adding this code to bootstrap/app.php :

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return realpath(__DIR__.'/../');
});
```

where **__DIR__.'/../'** is path to your public folder

Comment: A lot of good solutions provided by this thread, I choose this one. Thanks.

Comment: This one works just fine, help me to move a file to the public folder when I split the public folder from the laravel app folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In my case in Laravel 6.0 work this.
This file: ***bootstrap/app.php***

```
......
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__) );

$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return realpath(__DIR__.'/../httpdocs'); });
.....
```

I changed the *public_path()* folder, this example is with ***httpdocs*** folder, you can put watherver you want.

Comment: Only this one worked correctly for me. Compatible with artisan and HTTP requests. Good.

Comment: @X4748-IR Same here. Laravel 8.40

Answer (score 3):

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
  return base_path().'/mynewpublic';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [

    'public' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
             'root' => env('PATH_PUBLIC'),
       'visibility' => 'public',
       'url' => env('SITE_ROOT'),
    ],
```