# How to successfully change " public " folder name to " public_html " in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting, public-html

i had to ask this question here. i have seen so many other responses and none of them worked.. even after i editted the register function inside the app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php file - from a solution i got on laracasts.

```
public function register(){

    $this->app->bind('path.public_html', function(){
        return base_path(). '/public_html';
    });
    //
}
```

with this set, the hompage loaded successfully. 
but then after editting the welcome route to this ::

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   echo public_path();  //resolves to:: C:\xampp\htdocs\paprng\public
   exit;
   return view('welcome');
```

});

my public_path() function resolves to " C:\xampp\htdocs\paprng\public "..

please is there a string value of "public" somewhere in the laravel app. structure that requires editting to " public_html ", to avoid this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 change public\_path()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758901/laravel-5-change-public-path)

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the `public` folder for whatever you want, and then add this code to `index.php`

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

EDIT:

On your `bootstrap/app.php` file, add this code after the declaration of `$app` variable:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return realpath(__DIR__.'/../public_html');
});
```

Comment: i tried that and it did not work... this was one of my first options...

Comment: @Andaeiii added more explanation to the answer